# How to sense a wide range of voltage and output a certain voltage?

Tags: transistors, bias

I have an input voltage of 0-400V DC, I want to sense the input voltage as low as 100mV and output 5V and if voltage is lower than 100mV then output 0V.

I know it can easily be done with an op amp but I want to do it with discrete parts, the problem is whatever I do I can't get to bias the transistor correctly.

Because the input voltage can be high, I can't get R1 to a lower value and that causes the input voltage to have no influence on biasing the base current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxaPiT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- How can I sense an input voltage between 100mV and 400V and output 5V for example and if the input voltage is lower than 100mV output 0V?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple approach, modeling on the input stage of the venerable LM324/LM393 parts.
[image]

The input stage has a common-mode voltage which includes ground, allowing a simple voltage divider to select the reference voltage (R3/R4). Q8 (with R5) clips the input voltage to one diode drop.

Comment: Q8 is a nice touch - better than a regular diode clamp, keeps clamp current near zero for small inputs.

Comment: @SimonFitch Astute observation. If you simulate with a diode like 1N4148 it will misbehave at elevated temperatures.

Comment: I was wondering about how to clamp the input without requiring such a high input impedance R5. Do you have any ideas how to create a dynamic R5, that lowers significantly as the input potential approaches zero (or crosses, say, +20V)?

Comment: @SimonFitch Depletion-mode MOSFET, with or without a resistor, is one elegant approach.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you need to do is get the voltage into a range the transistors can handle. A voltage divider isn't going to work because it will scale everything down. If you use a 40:1 divider to bring 400 V down to 10 V then the 100 mV that you're trying to detect is going to be scaled to 2.5 mV. 100 mV is hard enough to detect with a transistor circuit, 2.5 mV is going to be 40 times as hard.

What you want to do instead limit the voltage. This can be done with a simple Zener diode. Since you only need accuracy below 1 V it won't matter if you clip the voltage to something above that. The Zener won't effect the lower voltages to any significant degree and anything over it's Vz will be limited.

The other problem is that a silicon transistor is not going to turn on with a base voltage of 100 mV relative to it's emitter. What you would need to do is offset the voltage to something above the transistor's Vbe.

Here's a circuit that limits the input to around 4.7 V, and then uses some diodes to create an offset voltage. The input voltage plus offset is then detected with a differential pair comparator circuit which drives a TTL type output stage.
[image: Vin > 100 mV detector circuit]

Ground for the detector circuit has to be isolated from the input voltage ground, which is connected to the reference voltage. The differential pair should be high beta transistors and the betas and tail resistance will affect the turn-on voltage, so the tail resistor value would probably have to be experimented with. The simulation works, but real world components are going to need some tinkering with. You'd also need to test it for temperature sensitivity as transistor circuits do tend to vary with temp. D2 in the circuit should help compensate it to some degree. And of course you're dealing with potentially lethal voltages so keep that in mind.

[image: Vin > 100 mV detector output graph]

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to go with a differential amplifier setup like Spehro's, because it's pretty stable over a wide temperature and supply voltage range, and requires no "trimming". Still, here's a four-transistor solution (using MOSFETs and BJTs):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxkIyw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I borrowed Q8 from Spehro's design (Q1 here), a stroke of clamping brilliance.

M1 is a source-follower, which buffers and offsets the input. M2/R6 is a voltage controlled current sink, competing with Q2, a *constant* current source, This source and sink combination has extremely high voltage gain around the point where their currents are equal, which I've set to be about 100μA when the input is 100mV.

The design suffers from a some drift of switching threshold with temperature, but it's not too bad, perhaps a few millivolts per °C. It relies on M2 having  a slightly higher \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ than M1, although with proper biasing you could easily adapt the circuit to compensate for *any* difference in \$V_{GS(TH)}\$.

VR1 is sets the switching threshold potential, which (unlike Spehro's LTP design) is needed because this *isn't* a differential amplifier; the dependence of switching threshold on \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ of both M1 and M2 requires some way to compensate.

The other potential problem is that the output is *low* when the input exceeds 100mV, instead of high:

[image]